# Java.util.logging only a row information with FileHandler

Tags: java

I'm using java.util.logging.FileHandler and I'm trying to overwrite the log information everytime on a File. I setted the FileHandler costructor to false, but carry on to append logs information. I've looked around on web but I didn't find a solution.

Below is my simple code:

```java
public class FileLog
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws SecurityException, IOException
    {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileLog.class.getName());
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

        FileHandler fh = null;
        boolean noException = false;
        String code = null;

        MyFormatter formatter = new MyFormatter();
        fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/MyLogFile.log", false);

        logger.addHandler(fh);

        fh.setFormatter(formatter); 

        while (!noException) {
            try {
                if (code == null)
                    throw new NullPointerException("Error code!!");
                else
                    noException = true;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("code "+code);
    }
}

public class MyFormatter extends Formatter
{
    // Create a DateFormat to format the logger timestamp.
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1000);
        builder.append(df.format(new Date(record.getMillis()))).append(" - ");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getSourceClassName()).append(".");
        builder.append(record.getSourceMethodName()).append("] - ");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getLevel()).append("] - ");
        builder.append(formatMessage(record));
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        // builder.append("\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This the output

```
05/11/2019 12:16:13.342 - [FileLog.main] - [WARNING] - Error Code!!
05/11/2019 12:16:27.317 - [FileLog.main] - [WARNING] - Error Code!!
```

It should write only the last exception. Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code checks for variable

> code

To be null.

Is it being set to a Non Null value anywhere?

Comment: I wanna test the exception condition. In this condition I can write on file the log message. This is the reason because I setted code=null.

Comment: Set the code to some non null value, in the catch clause. It will be set the first time exception occurs and the condition will fail in the second iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help